# Replication failed to connect to server [IP:27017] on first connect [MongoError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have setup Replication and trying to connect

```
URI:   
mongodb://[userName:password]@IP1:27017,
[userName:password]@IP2:27017/dbName? 
authSource=admin&w=1&replicaSet=replicaqa
```

but I am getting below error:

```
{ MongoError: failed to connect to server [host_name_ip1:27017] on first connect 
[MongoError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND [host_name_ArbiterIP] [host_name_ArbiterIP]:27017]
```

When I am individually trying to connect [IP1:27017] without replication it works.

Here is my Mongod.conf

```
systemLog:
    destination: file
    logAppend: true
    path: /var/mongodb/mongod.log

    # Where and how to store data.
    storage:
    dbPath: /data/var/lib/mongo
    journal:
    enabled: true
    #  engine:
    #  mmapv1:
    #  wiredTiger:

    # how the process runs
    processManagement:
    fork: true  # fork and run in background
    pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile
    timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

    # network interfaces
    net:
    port: 27017
    bindIp: 0.0.0.0

    security:
        authorization: "disabled"

    #operationProfiling:

    replication:
    replSetName: "replicaqa"
```

Am I missing something while configuring replication?

I can see mongod instance is started with replication where I can see (Primary>, Secondary> and Arbitary>  And each instance is on remote location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found mistake,

When we configure replication with rs.conf() we give domain name and update DNS in etc/hosts file.

In my case, I have updated it in mongo instance(etc/hosts) but not updated where my server is hosted (server is hosted on another instance).

Updated hosts file where Node service is running and now it's working for me.

when I connect without replication I was able to connect, but the issue is when I am trying to connect with Replication.

(No matter even if I have given IP address in my DB connection string URL. 
like

```
mongodb://[userName:password]@IP1:27017,[userName:password]@IP2:27017/dbName? 
authSource=admin&w=1&replicaSet=replicaqa
```

It will try to resolve the domain name. Because we have configured in rs.conf(), that's what happened with me  )

Path of hosts file in windows

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file
```

A path for hosts file in Linux/ CentOS

```
/etc/hosts
```

DNS

```
10.XX.XX.XX viavi.local
10.XX.XX.XXX domain_name_configured_while_replication
```